# JFreeChart - remove vertical lines

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a chart with a XYPlot. The chart uses dates on the X axis and values on the Y axis.

The white vertical lines shown here are above the date labels (that are hidden). I've managed to hide the labels, but these vertical lines are a pain. Can they be removed?

[image]